# Como fazer uma barra de progresso horizontal usando escala do css transform com scale3d?

Tags: javascript, css

```
var progress = 0.0 => 0.99 => 1;

//tipo de cálculo que eu gostaria...

 var obj = {
           'will-change': 'transform',
           'transform': 'scale3d('+progress+', 1, 1)'
 }
```

Eu tenho dois métodos que faz modificando o width, mas ambos não me parecem muito suaves:

**Javascript ES6:**

```
   window.onscroll = function () {
       scrollReading()
    };

    function scrollReading() {
        var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;

        var ready_bar = {
            width:scrolled + "%"
        }
    }
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
                    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
                    var height = $(document).height();
                    height = height - $(window).height();
                    var progress = top/height;
                    progress = progress * 100;
                    progress = progress + "%";
                   $("#progress-bar").width(progress);
                    progress = progress.substring(0, progress.length - 2);
                    progress = Math.round(progress * 9007199254740991) / 9007199254740991;
                    progress = progress + "%";
                    if(top / height === 1){
                        progress = "100%";
                    }
                   $("#percentage").html(progress);
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já resolvi: Era só dividir por 100: `80/100 => 0.8`

Reutilizando o método de **JavaScript puro**, foi possível fazer o efeito suave...

Eu precisava transformar um número de porcentagem, exemplo: 50% em forma de fração, considere que  1 = 100%, ou seja a metade de 1 seria 1/2, que é 0.5 = 50%, pois no atributo `transform`, utiliza-se porcentagem fracionária.

Para converter um valor de porcentagem, na forma fracionada, a solução foi dividir a porcentagem por 100, que resulta no valor do tipo: 0.x (quando for menor que 100%), 1 (quando for 100%), e 1.x quando for superior a 100%), sendo x o valor da porcentagem.